# Converting Gigabytes to bytes in helm templates

Tags: go, kubernetes-helm, go-templates

I have a chart for kafka, that has a pvc size defined in its values file like so: `20Gi`. I also have a configmap, that has a definition that it takes in bytes, like so: `log.retention.bytes=21474836480`.

I'm trying to get my chart to use the same value defined in `size` in the values file, in the configmap (hopefully, do some arithmetics on it before, like taking away a constant value to reserve some extra space)

I've been looking for a while to see if there is such a function built in to helm templates, or a way to create my own functions, with not much luck.

Ideally, I'm looking for something like this:

```
log.retention.bytes={{ .Values.persistence.size | convert-to-bytes | substract 10000 }}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [div](http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/math.html#div) Sprig function. For example, you could do:

```
{{ div .Values.persistence.size 1024 }}
```

If you'd like to perform a subtraction on the result, you can use the [sub](http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/math.html#sub) function. For example:

```
{{ sub (div .Values.persistence.size 1024) 10000 }}
```

Comment: would that function work? the `size` value is not a number, it's a string with 'Gi' at the end

Comment: Ah, no. You can use the [substr](http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/strings.html#substr) function as well to trim the suffix characters. This is not a generic (or very elegant) solution, but it should get the work done. You could also implement a generic function (supporting GI, Mi, etc using if/else conditions using [hasSuffix](http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/strings.html#hasprefix-and-hassuffix), but that's much more complicated)

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get results I need with this code:

```
log.retention.bytes={{ subf (trimSuffix "Gi"  .Values.persistence.size |  mulf 1073741824) 10000 | floor }}
```

`subf` and `mulf` are used because value in "Gi" can often be floor not intger and sub and mulf are supposed to be used only with integers.